# Dynamic number and position of arguments in a function

Tags: functions, function-construction, argument-patterns

I'm trying to write a function (A) which calls another function (B) (in my case `KroneckerProduct`) where the number and the position of the arguments of function (B) depend on the arguments of function (A).

Here an example of what I mean:

I have two matrices (1 and 2) and I want to do the `KroneckerProduct` of them `n` times (in the example `n=5`) where in position `a` and `b` (in the example `1` and `3`) I have `matrix2`, in all the other (`2`,`4`,`5`) I have `matrix1`.

```
matrix1 = IdentityMatrix[2];
matrix2 = {{2,2},{2,2}};

function[1, 3, 5] = KronekerProduct[
    matrix2, matrix1, matrix2, matrix1, matrix1
]
```

I can think several ways of doing that but none of them is elegant or short, while I think there is a compact way of doing it and I can't see it/

Thanks

Comment: is it always be about `matrix1` and `matrix2`? Don't you want them as a part of the input. Is it always be about `matrix2` being in exactly two spots? If not, please elaborate on what do you want to be able to input in general.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
What I need is just  three matrices (matrix 1, 2 and 3) where 2 of them are in position p1 and p2, but I asked just for two matrices for making the example simpler since the generalisation from 2 to 3 is straightforward: in this sense, jjc385 answer works nicely for what I need!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
function[p1_, p2_, n_, mat1_:matrix1, mat2_:matrix2] :=
 KroneckerProduct @@ (
   ConstantArray[mat1, n]
     // ReplacePart[p1|p2 -> mat2]
   )
```